# Database for P2P Application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sqlite, p2p

I need to create a software that follows the Peer-to-Peer distributed database architecture but I am unsure of which solution to use.

My first option is to SQLite which is free and doesn't rely on any services whatsoever compared to MS SQLServer. But can I rely SQLite for performance?

My second option is to use a full-fledged database solutions such as MySQL or MS SQLServer but I can't really rely on it if I want something service-free and independent can I?

Do you know any other database solution that fits my purpose?

My only is requirement is that it should be service free, independent and capable supporting large amount of data.

Edit: It has to be not internet dependent, offline database.

Comment: Not sure I understand your full use case. I know of [Dat Project](https://datproject.org/paper) creating 2 truly decentralized P2P databases (using NodeJS): [hyperdb](https://github.com/mafintosh/hyperdb) and [injestdb](https://github.com/beakerbrowser/injestdb).

Answer (score 0):

You can you aws RDBS and opt for free tier

Comment: Oh I forgot to precise, I need it to be offline. Not internet dependent.